# Why can't variable j initialization be in the termination expression of the for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements

```
public class Gameboard
{      
    public char[][] board;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Gameboard blank = new Gameboard(false);
        System.out.println("Printing blank gameboard:\n" + blank + "\n");
    }
    public Gameboard(boolean setup)
    {
        char[][] board = new char[8][8];
        if (!setup)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < board.length;i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < board[j].length;j++)//critical condition
                {
                    board[i][j] = '-';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know that column length is being used not the row length but the 2d array has the same length row-wise and column-wise.

Comment: You may try to use `for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++)`

Comment: @Paul Sorry my original answer was a bit lacking. Just added a bit more detail below, should answer your question now.

Comment: @Paul in your new edit the following line makes no sense `char[][] board = new char[board.length][board.width];`. First off arrays don't have a property called width so `board.width` wont even compile. Second off the board array hasnt been defined yet so you cant call "board.length" when the length hasnt even been set yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your logic is off here, since `i` counts through the first dimension and `j` through the second: what you really wanted was

```
for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++)
    {
        board[i][j] = '-';
    }
}
```

this issue of course was in the following line:

```
for (int j = 0; j < board[j].length; j++)
```

You are using `j` as the index on the first dimension of the board array but defining it as a value which goes up to a maximum length equal to the length of the second dimension. Which of course opens you up to the chance of having an index out of range, which is exactly what this code produces.

The reason you have a problem despite the fact that both dimensions are the same is because the conditional for the for loop to exit reevaluates each loop.

The logic is:

```
j < board[j].length
```

So at 7 you get:

```
7 < board[7].length
```

which is the same as:

```
7 < 8
```

Great it passes so goes through another loop but what happens at 8?

```
8 < board[8].length
```

Well 8 is out of bounds for the board array so it throws an exception, it simply cant evaluate it. the variable `i` however never reaches 8, it stops at 7, so you never get an index out of bounds in that case.

If you did the following it would work (but bad practice):

```
for(int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++)
```

Comment: I understand that I am counting the x dimensions instead of y. However, would not board[i].length be the same as board[j].length? So should the same answer be produced?

Comment: @Paul I updated my answer. Does it answer your question now?